# ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: No module named 'psycopg2._psycopg' zappa

Tags: python, django, postgresql, zappa, python-zappa

I am using zappa to deploy backend to the AWS Lambda. It worked well, until I decided to use PostgreSQL. I added it in the settings like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': config('DATABASE_NAME'),
        'USER': config('DATABASE_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': config('DATABASE_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': config('DATABASE_HOST'),
        'PORT': '5432'
    }
}
```

I am using AWS RDS. I installed psycopg2-binary and also psycopg2 (versions 2.8.6), but the issue remains. The python version is 3.8.

The full error log:

```
   [1621168086542] [ERROR] ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: No module named 'psycopg2._psycopg'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/handler.py", line 609, in lambda_handler
    return LambdaHandler.lambda_handler(event, context)
  File "/var/task/handler.py", line 240, in lambda_handler
    handler = cls()
  File "/var/task/handler.py", line 146, in __init__
    wsgi_app_function = get_django_wsgi(self.settings.DJANGO_SETTINGS)
  File "/var/task/zappa/ext/django_zappa.py", line 20, in get_django_wsgi
    return get_wsgi_application()
  File "/var/task/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup(set_prefix=False)
  File "/var/task/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/var/task/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/var/task/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/var/task/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/var/task/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 48, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/var/task/django/db/models/base.py", line 122, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "/var/task/django/db/models/base.py", line 326, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/var/task/django/db/models/options.py", line 206, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/var/task/django/db/__init__.py", line 28, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/var/task/django/db/utils.py", line 214, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/var/task/django/db/utils.py", line 111, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/var/task/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 29, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading psycopg2 module: %s" % e)
```

Comment: Check to make sure you installed `psycopg2-binary` when the virtual environment was active

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The (likely) issue is that you are building your lambda `.zip` package on MacOS. When you deploy your lambda function it is running in a Linux environment (specifically, AWS's Linux2 environment). The `psycopg2-binary` is different for the MacOS vs Linux environments, so if you build your lambda package (including the `psycopg2-binary`) on a Mac and then deploy to lambda you'll have the issues noted above.

You'll need to build your lambda function inside of an AWS Linux container. Here's a Dockerfile you could use to create a container inside of which you install the `psycopg2-binary` and build your lambda zip package. Then everything should work:

```
FROM amazonlinux:2.0.20200207.1

RUN cd /opt && \
    yum install -y gcc openssl-devel bzip2-devel libffi-devel wget tar gzip make && \
    wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.2/Python-3.8.2.tgz && \
    tar xzf Python-3.8.2.tgz && \
    cd Python-3.8.2 && \
    ./configure --enable-optimizations && \
    make altinstall && \
    rm -f /opt/Python-3.8.2.tgz && \
    echo "alias python3=python3.8" > ~/.bashrc
```

Note the amaonzonlinux:2.0 operating system, then I just install python 3.8.2 into the environment (you could use a different version of python if desired). From there you can copy in your code and build your lambda `.zip` package and deploy to lambda.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the custom compiled psycopg2 library for AWS Lambda [aws-psycopg2](https://pypi.org/project/aws-psycopg2/).

Answer (score 4):

I built my lambda package on macOS Big Sur with `zappa==0.53.0` and `django==3.2.5`. I started getting this error after I upgraded to `psycopg2-binary==2.9.1`. Rolling back to `psycopg2-binary==2.8.6` fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Rolling back to psycopg2-binary==2.8.6 worked for me. thanks @leila

Comment: I was having the same error with the version 2.9.5, rolling back to the 2.8.6 solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I installed `aws-psycopg2` (1.2.1) to resolve the 500 error that I was getting from AWS every time I executed a post request.

**Note:** I kept `psycopg2` (2.9.1) in order so that my local app could still function.

I have a flask app (python 3.8) deployed to AWS lambda via Zappa.  Local and hosted versions of my app are both hooked up to an AWS RDS PostgreSQL db.  Trying to avoid using a docker container to keep my stack as simple as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same issue popping out despite using `psycopg2-binary` successfully for a long time. I found the following workaround using lambda layers which seems to go in the good future proof direction:

In your zappa config, add the following line:

```
"layers": ["arn:aws:lambda:<region>:<account_id>:layer:<layer_name>:<layer_version>"]
```

Referencing one of the layers provided in this [repo](https://github.com/jetbridge/psycopg2-lambda-layer) (it depends on your AWS region and Python version) and remove `psycopg2-binary` from your environment.

One of the added benefit is that it should reduce your package size as well.